# Need some assistance involving a forking in C

Tags: c

Hello so I've been working on this for quite awhile now and cannot figure it out.
I'm trying to set up a connection to a client using a specific port number. For some reason the child process is exiting if my While loop is included in the code. When I take the while loop out everything executes as intended. Any guidance?

Here's my code

```
> #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Please enter a port");
    } else {
        printf("test2");
        int socketfd;
        pid_t pid, sid;

        //Fork
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pid > 0) {
            printf("exiting");
            exit(0);

        } 

        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Hi");
            sid = setsid();
            if (sid < 0){
                    printf("failure");
            }
            //Start the Daemon
            printf("Test");
            socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if(socketfd < 0){
                printf("socket error");
            }
            int portNumber = atoi(argv[1]); //Port number entered in by user.   
            struct sockaddr_in server;
            struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
            bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server)); // Clear buffer for server address
            server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
            server.sin_port = htons(portNumber); 
            server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
            socklen_t clientLength;
            printf("Test3");    
            if (bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
            {
                perror("bind call failed");
            }
            printf("Test5");
            listen(socketfd, 5);
            clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
            printf("Test6");
            while(1) {
                int client_socketfd;
                int x; 
                client_socketfd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientLength);
                if(client_socketfd == -1){
                    perror("ERROR: \n");
                }
                FILE * pFile;
                char receivedFile[1000];
                char rawData[1000];
                bzero(receivedFile, 1000);
                if (read(client_socketfd,receivedFile,1000) == -1){
                    perror("Read Failure");
                }
                printf("Received File %s",receivedFile); 
                pFile = fopen(receivedFile, "r");
                if(pFile == NULL){
                    perror("Cannot open file"); 
                }
                if(fgets(rawData,1000,pFile) != NULL) {
                    int fileLength = strlen(rawData);
                    for(x = 0; x < fileLength; x++){
                        printf("%s\n",rawData[x]);
                    }
                } else {
                    perror("Nothing in the file!\n");
                }
            }   


        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what happens when I compile and run the above code:

[image: Compile and Run]

Here's the test I did to source the issue to the while loop.

```
 > #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        if (argc < 2) {
            printf("Please enter a port");
        } else {
            printf("test2");
            int socketfd;
            pid_t pid, sid;

            //Fork
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("Fork failed");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (pid > 0) {
                printf("exiting");
                exit(0);

            } 

            if (pid == 0) {
                printf("Hi");
                sid = setsid();
                if (sid < 0){
                        printf("failure");
                }
                //Start the Daemon
                printf("Test");
                socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                if(socketfd < 0){
                    printf("socket error");
                }
                int portNumber = atoi(argv[1]); //Port number entered in by user.   
                struct sockaddr_in server;
                struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
                bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server)); // Clear buffer for server address
                server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
                server.sin_port = htons(portNumber); 
                server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
                socklen_t clientLength;
                printf("Test3");    
                if (bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
                {
                    perror("bind call failed");
                }
                printf("Test5");
                listen(socketfd, 5);
                clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
                printf("Test6");

            }


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This code successfully enters the child and prints out all the "Tests"

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy code I'm going to go through and clean it up after I solve this bug.

Comment: "*When I take the while loop out ...*" which code does this include, everything inside the loop as well? "*... everything executes as intended.*" which is how please?

Comment: And the second snippet is not "*exiting*"?-S

Comment: The second snippet exits, however what i'm attempting to do is run the while loop continuously so I can connect another program to this one. On the first snippet it doesn't run anything in the if(pid == 0) section and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Change all those `printf()`s to have a trailing `\n`, which would flush their output to the console: Change `printf("Hi");` to be `printf("Hi\n");`.

Comment: Also you  might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to help yourself in such situations.

Comment: Or even better send debug-logging to `stderr` but to `stdout` using `fprintf(stderr, "pid %d: %s\n", getpid(), "step 42");`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I couldn't spot that bug.... hah. Yeah I need to improve my debugging techniques thanks for the link and advice!